# Where is the CTC region of a Kerr Black Hole?

Tags: general-relativity, event-horizon, singularities, kerr-metric, closed-timelike-curve

CTCs are found in the region where $r < 0$ . That should be just inside the ring singularity, since in Boyer Lindquist coordinate system $r = 0$ means ring singularity. Does that mean this image showing CTC outside the ringularity is wrong, or I am missing something?

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/This-is-how-light-cones-behave-in-Kerr-Newman-spacetimes-For-r-0-r-1-and-computations_fig2_1760606

Comment: I am hazarding a guess that CTC = Closed Timelike Curves?

Comment: yes, that's what a  CTC is.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something. In a text where $r < 0$ is possible, the singular ring is a curve, not a surface: its equation in B-L coordinates is $(r = 0, \cos \theta = 0)$.

In contrast, $r = 0$ *is* the equation of a surface: it consists of two disks $(r = 0, \cos \theta > 0)$ and $(r = 0, \cos \theta < 0)$ together with the singular ring, their common boundary. The 2 disks are made of regular points: they are actually 2 manholes through which you can reach into negative space.

The picture is ambiguous: if the text from which you got it claims the CTC is in negative space (not sure, the pic is clipped), then it lies *below* the region $r = 0$ rather than just *outside*.

Comment: Just to add that the planar disk inside the ring singularity is actually a discontinuity in the metric components. This is shown in H Ohanian’s book.

Comment: @Cham in such an interpretation, $r < 0$ is impossible.